# Superimpose 3 qplots (ggplot2) into just one single graphic to print/save

Tags: r, ggplot2

I started to use ggplot in order to generate some graphs. I am using the very basic of the sample they have in their site for an "step graph":  `http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_step.html`

I need something like the last example in that page. The issue I found is the example is in one DF and every Y has a different value in X. I have 3 sets to plot, all of them has the same X and Y values in all X. I don't get how to produce the graphic in R. In excel I create the first line and add the other 2 as new data series but I am lost in ggplot. Any advise is really appreciated.

My plot commands are now as this (each of them with different df):

```
qplot(seq_along(x), x, data = df, geom="step", colour = trt)
```

Is there a way to have one df with all the values? Any example will be great. Thanks in advance for your time

EDIT>>>>

Here is some data to see:

```
head(df_nourbanas)
     x        trt
1    3 no urbanas
2   85 no urbanas
3  450 no urbanas
4  942 no urbanas
5 1362 no urbanas
6 1699 no urbanas

head(df_urbanas)
     x     trt
1   65 urbanas
2 1019 urbanas
3 2192 urbanas
4 3164 urbanas
5 3847 urbanas
6 4338 urbanas

head(df_todas)
     x   trt
1    3 todas
2  152 todas
3 1481 todas
4 3158 todas
5 4564 todas
6 5593 todas
```

And this is what I need to have (this is in excel) directly form R using the steps mode
[image: r_steps]

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example? And possibly and example of the graph you would like to have.

Comment: How about merging your three data sets with merge() so you've got them all in one df, then plot as for the example?

Comment: Paul. Just added some example data.  Ben. I don't know how to merge those 3 df in order to have just one for this qplot. (I tried some variations without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having problems because you are using implicit information in the data set: the order the points are, which becomes the x-axis position.  Make this explicit and things become easier.

```
df_nourbanas$idx <- seq(length=nrow(df_nourbanas))
df_urbanas$idx <- seq(length=nrow(df_urbanas))
df_todas$idx <- seq(length=nrow(df_todas))
```

Now these 3 data sets can be combined.

```
df_all <- rbind(df_nourbanas, df_urbanas, df_todas)
```

and plotting them is just

```
ggplot(df_all, aes(x=idx, y=x, colour=trt)) +
  geom_step()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brian. This worked as I needed. I have to figure some of your code anyway.